# iOS: Create a dynamic registration form

Tags: ios, forms, csv, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on a registration form app. Right now I'm trying to come up with a way to to dynamically create forms. Right now I have a hardcoded form, with hardcoded questions, that will save the form data into a .csv file. Here is some of the code:

```
// saves text field data in comma separated CSV file format
    NSString *formData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@\n",
                          self.nameTextfield.text, self.emailTextfield.text,
                          self.phoneTextfield.text, self.termTextfield.text,
                          self.schoolTextfield.text, self.graduationTextfield.text,
                          self.gpaTextfield.text, degreeString,
                          self.interestTextfield.text, groupString,
                          appliedString];

    // get document directory path
    NSString *documentDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                           NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *csv = @".csv";
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _eventName.text, csv];
    // append results.csv onto doc path
    NSString *event = [documentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    // creates folder if it does not exist
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:event]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:event contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:event];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[formData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
```

Basically I want to be able to create a form on the app that can be any number of questions, and either uses segmented controls or text inputs. One issue I see already is formatting the file in the comma separated format. For instance, if the app creates 5 questions, how do you format the file such that formData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@\n"] without hardcoding that in?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (but not the only) way to correctly create dynamic form is to build it of typical blocks (such as switch-block, textfield-block, etc). You can add these blocks to view manually or use UITableView for example. Also you need data structure describing concrete form (number and types of blocks).

Formatting file is no problem since you always can use NSMutableString and append values one by one.

Comment: NSMutableString is probably what I need to get this working. I can create an array of questions and what control they are, then run that array through a for loop and do stuff to it!